# How to install Linux Kernel 2.6.11 using source code

Tags: kernel, downgrade

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I would like to change my Linux Kernel version to 2.6.11(downgrade).

Are any dependencies to downgrade? 
For example, libraries to help source code compile, Ubuntu version...

Comment: The closest Ubuntu kernels that used a kernel close to 2.6.11 were 5.04 (2.6.10) and 5.10 (2.6.12).  Both are more than a decade out of date, and upstream the kernel 2.6.11 reached EOL in June 2005.  It's a security risk if you're on a web-based machine - are you sure it's a good idea?

Comment: It's just my assignment, so I won't use it after downgrading.

Comment: I tried to compile 2.6.11 source code, but compile said 'code model kernel does not support PIC mode'. I found that it is the GCC problem. So I wanted to know which version of GCC is suitable for compiling kernel 2.6.11.

Comment: Frodo, sorry I haven't compiled kernels in many years (possibly since 2.6 days).  I'd start with looking for version around `gcc` that was around 2005 (the time of 2.6.11), though it may still compile up to 10.04's time (it still used 2.6; kernel reversion numbers were incremented  differently back then) but this is only a guess

Comment: There's a fair chance that 18.04 would not boot with 2.6-series kernels. Too much have changed in the passing time.

Comment: Consider to get whole distribution of previous Ubuntu (see [distrowatch table](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ubuntu) for details) with similar kernel: Ubuntu 5.04 had 2.6.10, Ubuntu 5.10 had 2.6.12 or get Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with 2.6.32. Then install it in VirtualBox. If this is an assignment, then it is odd - the kernel ABI was changed, the GCC was changed and so on.

Comment: guiverc,  vidarlo, N0rbert Thank you for answering my question. My class's text book, Understanding the Linux Kernel, explains Linux Kernel using version 2.6. Because of that, it might be an assignment.